# Swapping int for constant in c

Tags: c

I am modifying some code that was supplied to me for handling the data transfer between an FPGA and a processor using DMA. There is a constant defined at the top of the page as such `#define NUM_WORDS_IN_MEMORY(20)` that represents the number of words being transferred to the FPGA. The data that I need to transfer to the FPGA does not always come in the same size packets so I figured I would replace NUM_WORDS_IN_MEMORY with a variable. NUM_WORDS_IN_MEMORY is only used in three places all in the same function. The first two, are for loops that function as expected when replaced with the variable size. The final usage writes the length to the DMA's length register. If I change the other two usages to size and leave this as NUM_WORDS_IN_MEMORY it still works. This is the problematic code fragment

```
//This is a definition for writing to DMA
#define alt_write_word(dest, src) (*ALT_CAST(volatile uint32_t *, (dest)) = (src))

...
...

addr = fpga_dma_virt + DMA_LEN_REG_OFST; // Address to write to
data = NUM_WORDS_IN_MEMORY * sizeof(uint32_t);
alt_write_word(addr, data);
```

It appears to me as switching from NUM_WORDS_IN_MEMORY to size tells the FPGA to read beyond the expected length. Is there a difference between an Int and a constant as defined above?

Comment: As long as the number is the same, no

Comment: that code doesn't look right. src is not pointing to data at all.

Comment: @CacahueteFrito Both are set to a value of 7.

Comment: Does your hardware *allow* you to use a different transfer size?  In particular, does it allow you to use the particular size you are trying to use?

Comment: Try replacing `NUM_WORDS_IN_MEMORY` with a variable, but set the variable to 20. If that doesn't work (which would be very surprising), let us know. But if it *does* work (which is the expected outcome), then the problem is unrelated to changing the constant to a variable.

Comment: @johnelemans The alt_write_word functions as expected. The length is written to the DMA register but the right length is only written when the value is set using #define instead of an int.

Comment: @Dacoolinus If both are 7, I guess both are failing

Comment: @user3386109 Setting the variable to 20 works. Is there a reason as to why 20 might work but 7 would not?

Comment: Maybe the DMA controller uses a 16-bit transfer size, and therefore can only move an even number of bytes.

Comment: @user3386109 Thank you! As long as I'm using multiple's of 4 it is working. I still don't understand why the constant 7 worked though.

Comment: Sometimes things appear to work when they actually aren't working. Such is the nature of undefined behavior, the bane of every C programmer.

Answer (score 1):

The DMA controller uses a 16-bit transfer size. I was assuming that since I was multiplying size by sizeof(uint32_t) which has a value of 4 that there would always be an even number of bytes. If I change from a size = 7(what I had previously) to size = 8 everything works.